# Checking Visual Studio code into source control - what do I need to check in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, cruisecontrol

I have a new project written in Visual Studio 2010, and I have checked all of the code and the project files into our source control system, however checking the code out and doing a build via MSBuild doesn't work in CruiseControl, it looks like there are dependancies that are captured somewhere in a file that I haven't checkin. Any ideas where these are held, or what am I missing ?
Thanks

**Update**

I think somewhere in the checkin I managed to remove some assemblies (don't ask me how I did it) from the references, so I added these back in, and it all works now. So the answer is to check everything that is checked in!

Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: How could we possibly answer that without you telling us what the error messages are??

Comment: Normally the source control system automatically adds all the needed files when you add it to source control . What ssc are you using , and what does msbuild barf on ?

Comment: Also you might have missing references to assemblies, which usually are not part of the source code, but required for a successful build nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault! I managed to delete some assemblies from the references